# How to select ul>li on checkbox change and trigger change ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox and with the change event of that, I need to select `ul>li` value `"More than 24 months ago"` and trigger event change for `ul`. How to do that?

```
    <div id="dnn_ctr2489_DNNWebControlContainer_ctl00_ddlRecentGraduate_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_PersonifyDefault " style="display:none;">
       <div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="width:100%;">
         <ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
            <li class="rcbItem ">Within the past 12 months</li>
            <li class="rcbItem ">Within the past 13 to 24 months</li>
            <li class="rcbItem ">More than 24 months ago</li>
            <li class="rcbItem ">Not Applicable</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
```

checkbox event

```
$("#dnn_ctr2489_DNNWebControlContainer_ctl00_chkConfirmEligibility").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please clarify. _"I need to select ul>li value "_. List items don't have values like form elements do. Also, _"and trigger event change for ul"_ Lists don't have change events like form elements do either.

Comment: Not enough to go by, also where is the checkbox? why won't you use some ids, if a checkbox is present or selected it can hold the value in it... the html you gave is lacking... please expand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do something to the parent-list of each list-item containing that string, whenever that checkbox changes, you can try something like the following:

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]');
const lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

checkbox.onchange = ({ target }) => {
 [...lis].forEach(li => {
    if (li.textContent === 'More than 24 months ago') {
      li.closest('ul').style.backgroundColor = target.checked 
        ? 'green'
        : '';
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="rcbItem ">Within the past 12 months</li>
    <li class="rcbItem ">Within the past 13 to 24 months</li>
    <li class="rcbItem ">More than 24 months ago</li>
    <li class="rcbItem ">Not Applicable</li>
</ul>
<label>
Click me
<input type="checkbox">
</label>
```